# Создание службы для nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2, службы

Есть скрипт на nodejs который работает в фоновом режиме c помощью pm2, но оно не отображется в службах Windows. Хочу чтобы моя программа отображалось в службах, чтобы пользователь смог просматривать в диспетчере задач. Как создать службу для ОС, не только Windows но и для Linux? Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Насчёт windows не знаю, но насчёт linux подскажу.
У pm2 есть команда startup которая добавит запущенные node.js процессы в службы.
Так же почитайте про save

Comment: А вообще вот мои рабочие команды которые автоматически поднимают сохранённые процессы node.js при перезагрузке сервера:

pm2 startup systemd

sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u $USER --hp /home/$USER

sudo systemctl start pm2-$USER

systemctl status pm2-$USER